# Conditions in Ternary Operator - Java

Tags: java, if-statement, return

I have a simple if/elseif condition which I'm trying to convert it into a return statement with Ternay Operator for code redundancy but I have not been able to.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Here's my code snippet :

```
if (val.equals("a")||val.equals("s")){
    return true;
} 
else if (val.equals("b")||val.equals("t")) {
     return false;
}

return true;
```

Could someone please suggest on how to proceed with return statement(Ternary Operator) for the above if/else-if ?

Comment: Please don't change the question after people have answered. If you have a new question, post it as a new question.

Comment: ok I will revert back my question and add a new one, Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need for a conditional operator here. Your code will return `true` so long as `val` is neither `b` nor `t`:

```
return !(val.equals("b") || val.equals("t"));
```

or:

```
return !val.equals("b") && !val.equals("t");
```

The first condition around `a` and `s` is completely irrelevant, as the "default" `return true` at the bottom already includes those cases.

EDIT: Now that you've changed the return type to `int`, this *would* be reasonable to use with the conditional operator:

```
return val.equals("b") || val.equals("t") ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: I have edited my question, Instead of boolean can an integer be returned?

Comment: @user3652212: Well it *can* be, although I'd argue that's a strange API design. It's also not a great idea to edit a question in a way that makes all existing answers invalid...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes hereafter I will make sure I do not edit my question once it has been answered.

Answer (score 4):

```
return !(val.equals("b") || val.equals("t"))
```

The rest is redundant, `val` cannot equal "a" or "s" and equal "b" or "t" at the same time, so you basically need to check if it equals "b" or "t", and return `false` in this case, and `true` in any other case.

Answer (score 2):

```
return !(val.equals("b") || val.equals("t"));
```

This is the only condition that returns false - so you don't need to check the first condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
return !(val.equals("b") || val.equals("t"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the follwing:

```java
boolean b = ( val.equals("b") || val.equals("t") ) ? false : true;
return b;
```

Comment: What about e.g. `"c"`? That should return `true` as well.

Comment: Should have inversed the statements. Thx @Baz

Comment: When you're doing `x = condition ? false : true;` it's a flag that you're being redundant. :-) Simply `x = !condition;` is sufficient. *(not my dv)*

Comment: Yes absolutelly and I would never write such a line when I'm developing, but the guy asked for a ternary expression and I wanted to stick to the topic.